# curl: (33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume

Tags: curl

I am trying to resume download of a file using curl.

I am using the below command:

```
curl -L -o /home/guest/1.mp4 -C - "url_to_download"


** Resuming transfer from byte position 4967989
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   207    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.
```

I gives the above error. How to get the proper message of finished downloading. Because based on this i have to start another command if the download is completed.

```
$ curl --version 
curl 7.53.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.53.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2k zlib/1.2.11 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libicu/58.2) libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

Comment: It was so easy to resume download with `wget`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was running:

```
curl -O -C - "my_url"
```

I had got a similar error:

```
curl: (33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.
[2]-  Exit 33                 nohup curl -O -C - "my_url"
```

---

**Solution** by trial and error:

I added the -L tag to this and then the download resumed from where the last byte it stopped at.

```
curl -L -O -C - "my_url"

** Resuming transfer from byte position 8637478709
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 11 1598M   11  176M    0     0  1138k      0  0:23:57  0:02:38  0:21:19 1131k
```

---

Note:

- "-L" : follows redirects
- "-O" : write output to a local file named like the remote file we get.
- "-C - " : continues previously unfinished download

---